# SQL Server - parameter with unknown number of multiple values

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm creating a grid that has two columns: `Name` and `HotelId`. The problem is that data for this grid should be sent with a single parameter of `VARCHAR type` and should look like this:

```
@Parameter = 'Name1:5;Name2:10;Name3:6'
```

As you can see, the parameter contains Name and a number that represents ID value and you can have multiple such entries, separated by "**;**" symbol.

My first idea was to write a query that creates a `temp table` that will have two columns and populate it with data from the parameter.

How could I achieve this? It seems like I need to split the parameter two times: by the "**;**" symbol for each row and then by "**:**" symbol for each column. 
How should I approach this?

Also, if there is any other more appropriate solution, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a table-type parameter or a string splitter; both of which have 100's of example of here on SO. Personally, I recommend the former.

Comment: add schema ,with sample data and expected result

Comment: Yes the table type parameter is far and above the best solution here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First Drop the #temp table if Exists...**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp', 'U') IS NOT NULL
/*Then it exists*/
DROP TABLE #temp
```

Then create `#temp table`

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (v1 VARCHAR(100))
```

Declare all the `@Paramter....`

```
DECLARE @Parameter VARCHAR(50)
SET @Parameter= 'Name1:5;Name2:10;Name3:6'
DECLARE @delimiter nvarchar(1) 
SET @delimiter= N';';
```

Here, Inserting all `@parameter` value into #temp table using '**;**' separated..

```
INSERT INTO #temp(v1)
SELECT * FROM(

SELECT v1 = LTRIM(RTRIM(vals.node.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')))
FROM (
    SELECT x = CAST('<root><data>' + REPLACE(@Parameter, @delimiter, '</data><data>') + '</data></root>' AS XML).query('.')
) v
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/root/data') vals(node)
)abc
```

After inserting the value into `#temp` table..get all the value into '**:**' seprated...

```
select  Left(v1, CHARINDEX(':', v1)-1) as Name , STUFF(v1, 1, CHARINDEX(':', v1), '') as HotelId FROM #temp
```

Then you will get this type of **Output**

[image]